# Factor $a^2+3b^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Using cubic root factor the expression $$a^2+3b^3$$
We have
$$a^2+3b^3=\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2}\right)^3+\left(\sqrt[3]{3b^3}\right)^3 \tag{1}
$$$$
=\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{3b^3}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{a^4}-\sqrt[3]{3a^2b^3}+\sqrt[3]{9b^6}\right)\tag{2}
$$$$
=\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+b\sqrt[3]{3}\right)\left(a\sqrt[3]{a}-b\sqrt[3]{3a^2}+b^2\sqrt[3]{9}\right)\tag{3}$$

Am I right?

Comment: For $a=b=1$, we have $a^2+3b^3=4$, but the last line is different, namely $(1+\sqrt[3]{3})(1-\sqrt[3]{3}+1)$.

Comment: The last term of the last factor is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Equation $(2)$ does not [expand or simplify](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Ba%5E2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3b%5E3%7D%29%28%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Ba%5E4%7D-%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3a%5E2b%5E3%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B9b%5E6%7D%29) to equation $(1).\quad$ It appears that the last term of equation $(2)$ is not right.

One way of factoring uses substitution in steps to make things easier to see.

\begin{align*}
\space &a^2+3b^3=x^3+y^3\\
=\space &(x + y) (x^2 - x y + y^2)\\
=\space &
\bigg( \sqrt[3]{a^2} +  \sqrt[3]{3b^3}\bigg)   
 \bigg( (\sqrt[3]{a^2}) ^2
 -  (\sqrt[3]{a^2})  (\sqrt[3]{3b^3}) + (\sqrt[3]{3b^3})^2\bigg)\\
=\space &
\bigg( \sqrt[3]{a^2} +  \sqrt[3]{3b^3}\bigg)   
 \bigg( \big(\sqrt[3]{a^2}\big) ^2 -  \sqrt[3]{3a^2b^3} + \big(\sqrt[3]{3b^3}\big)^2\bigg)  
\\
=\space &a^2+3b^3
\quad\text{for }\quad b\le 0
\space \text{ or }\space a^2+3b^3 > 0
\end{align*}

WoframAlpha supports this factoring [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+++%5Cbigg%28+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Ba%5E2%7D+%2B++%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3b%5E3%7D%5Cbigg%29+++++%5Cbigg%28+%5Cbig%28%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Ba%5E2%7D%5Cbig%29+%5E2+-++%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3a%5E2b%5E3%7D+%2B+%5Cbig%28%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B3b%5E3%7D%5Cbig%29%5E2%5Cbigg%29++)
.

Also, here is an example showing the validity of these factors. Let

\begin{align*}
f(a,b) &=\bigg( \sqrt[3]{a^2} +  \sqrt[3]{3b^3}\bigg)
&f(1,1) & = 1 + 3^{1/3} 
\\
g(a,b)&= ​​\bigg( \sqrt[3]{a^2} ^2 -  \sqrt[3]{3a^2b^3} + \sqrt[3]{3b^3}^2\bigg)
&g(1,1) & = 1 - 3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3}  
\\
h(a,b)&=f\big(a,b\big) \cdot g\big(a,b\big) 
&h(1,1)& = \big(1+ 3^{1/3}\big)\\
&&&\space\cdot\space\big(1 - 3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3} \big)
\\&&&=4\\ 
i(a,b)&=a^2+3b^3    &i(1,1) &=4
\\  \end{align*}

Another method assumes that the sum is zero,
that $b$ is positive,
and the factors are complex.

\begin{align*}
&a^2+3b^3=0\implies a=\pm\sqrt{-3b^3}\\
\space & a^2 - \big(\sqrt{3b^3}i\big)^2
\\
=\space & \bigg( a - \big(\sqrt{3b^3}i\big)\bigg)
\bigg( a + \big(\sqrt{3b^3}i\big)\bigg)
\end{align*}